# Class attribute of type DataFrame cannot be inspected in pycharm debugger session

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, pycharm

I have set up a function and a class method in python 3.6 that both fetch the boston data set. In the latter case the boston data set is stored as a class attribute of the object.

The 'Bunch' type is converted to a pandas dataframe in the exact same manner in both instances.

When I inspect both in the pycharm debugger, using the View as Array / Data Frame functionality of pycharm...

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/viewing-as-array.html

...I can view the df that results by calling the function and assigning the output to a variable, but not the df that is assigned to the class attribute of the instantiated object.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
import pandas as pd

# define function to get boston data
def get_boston():
    boston = load_boston()
    df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
    df['target'] = boston.target
    return df


class MyData:
    """
    Object with boston data as attribute
    """

    def __init__(self, raw_data=None, processed_data=None):
        self.raw_data = raw_data
        self.processed_data = processed_data

    def get_data(self):
        boston = load_boston()
        df = pd.DataFrame(boston.data, columns=boston.feature_names)
        df['target'] = boston.target
        self.raw_data = df


my_data_1 = MyData()
my_data_1.get_data()

my_data_2 = get_boston()

print(my_data_1.raw_data.head(5))
```

When I run the debugger session, I can inspect the my_data_2 variable with the 'View as Data Frame' function in pycharm, but when I do the same for the class attribute raw_data, the 'View as Data Frame' dialog window shows - 'nothing to show', even though I can print it's content to the console properly (using pandas.DataFrame.head() method)

I am using PyCharm 2018.3.3 on Ubuntu Linux.